# My Ubuntu 14.04 just shows the desktop and nothing else!

Tags: 14.04, desktop-environments, bug-reporting

I shutdown my laptop for the last time and it had run good, but when I turn it on, now, it just shows my desktop and its icons, also no short-key runs and I can just run software which are in the desktop! I can't run terminal as well! I restarted it, yet, it goes wrong so far.

I installed unity plugin for times and reset it also, but it would not change.
What should I do?

Comment: There are always 6 terminals available. Press CTRL+ALT+F1 all the way through CTRL+ALT+F6 to get these. CTRL+ALT+ F7 is where the GUI is running, so that you can get back to it.

Comment: I run combizconfig by tty1, but i can't find unity plugin in it!

Comment: I tried all of them, nothing happened, how can I repair ubuntu?